# iOSOpenDev application building error

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

I have a problem when trying to make an application in Xcode. When trying to install the app to an iPod I get this error:

```
unable to create `Calculator.app/Calculator.app/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboardc/UIViewController-2.nib': No such file or directory
```

I am using iOSOpenDev so app installs via SSH.
[Full log here](http://pastebin.com/WbLZEMpn)

Comment: Do you actually have a file called `UIViewController-2.nib` in your project?

Comment: @Aggressor , i have only one ViewController. [link](http://img.ctrlv.in/img/15/07/14/55a4d0b4261db.png)

Comment: UPD: if i press BUILD (cmd+shift+b) it's no errors. But if i BUILD FOR PROFILING (cmd+shift+i) xcode show this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is re-create project in new xcode. Project i used was created for ios 6.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have

1. Set storyboard entry point set correctly
2. You have set Main Interface set correctly in General-> Deployment into.
3. You are not missing any UI file from project.if so then add in build phases compile headers.

Comment: Thank you for response. All that you wrote set correctly